# Can a wheelspin give you a car you already have?

Tags: forza-horizon-2

Everytime you level up you get a go at the wheelspin(slots) which awards bonus credits or even a free car.

Can the Wheelspin give you a car you already bought? or won previously?

Comment: I don't think so, but I have only won two cars via wheelspin so far.

Comment: so far level 80 I haven't seen any duplicates. Still. there is a TON of cars in the game, so I can't be sure.

Comment: @Rapitor I'm at level 158 and just heard about this wheelspin... does that mean I get 158 tries at the wheel? Plus, where is it located?

Comment: how did you get all the way to level 158 without spinning once, @TekiusFanatikus? Anyway, yeah. you can find your spins in the progression tab on the pause menu and you *will* be spinning for all you missed.

Comment: @Rapitor errrr, just going through the showcase events at +85% difficulty. I've just gotten Journey Man in Saint Martin, currently grinding away in Nice. Nothing fancy really. On Xbox 360 BTW, not sure if that makes a difference...

Comment: @Rapitor is this an Xbox One only thing? I'm in there, on my 360, looking in the Progress tab and I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Rapitor wait, I think I just figured it out... this is while leveling up online? If so, I was thinking this was for single player.

Comment: Levels are the same in multiplayer and singleplayer. Platform does not matter. You might want to ask a new question and post screenshots if you are still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes it can**.  I have just confirmed it.  The game will say that you already own it and you will have two options: **Sell** or **Add to garage**.  See the screenshot I took below:

[image]